# How to view Apache Derby schema configured in Apache ofbiz

Tags: derby, ofbiz

I am new to Apache ofbiz. I went through the tutorial and have deployed the default version of Apache ofbiz. I do understand that the database in Apache ofbiz is by default Derby. While starting the ofbiz I can see that many tables are getting created. 
However I am not able to view the schema in Apache derby. I need guidance on viewing the database schema.

Comment: You can use `Data source Explorer` view in `Eclipse`

Comment: Where to point the schema?

Comment: You create new connection with Embedded Derby option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools you can use to view the schema of an Apache Derby database.

Derby itself offers the "ij" tool, with its "show tables" and "describe" commands.

There are graphical tools, such as Squirrel: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

There are programmatic tools, such as the JDBC metadata classes, or the DDLUtils library.